# For loop using OutPutStreamWriter

Tags: java, android, for-loop, streamwriter

I am able to use `OutputStreamWriter` to write a single string to my php successfully. I am struggling to figure out how to use a for loop to write multiple strings though.

For the for loop, I would just like the string to be written 5 times. This is what I have come up with:

```
OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
ow = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

JSONObject objLog = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    objLog.put("a", "a");
    objLog.put("b", "b");
    String data = objLog.toString();
    ow.write(data);
}
```

When I run this part of the code, only 1 of the 5 gets written to my server and all the data is empty. I know my php code is correct because it runs properly without the for loop. Thinking this through, ow.write(data) should write to my php 5 times, right? Why does it only write to it once?